# How to set TLS 1.1 in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to enable tls 1.1 while script is running and to revert back to normal when the script is finished. How would I be able to do this?

Googling this hasn't yielded any results.

Comment: this is what i use to set the TLS stuff >>> `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12, tls11, tls'` <<< from what i understand it all returns to the standard settings when PoSh exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try{
    $InitialSecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11

    # Your code here
}
finally {
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $InitialSecurityProtocol
{
```

You don't *need* the try/finally block, but it will help with ensuring that the TLS setting is reverted upon completion of the script. The `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` setting will always be reset in a new PowerShell session, too, so unless you're going to be reusing the session that you're in, you don't really have to worry about the value being changed.

If you want TLS 1.1 or 1.2, you can specify:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Note that if you have a really old version of PowerShell (anything without .Net 4.5 installed, IIRC) then the above command will not work. This is because TLS 1.1 and 1.2 were not added until .Net 4.5 added them to the .Net framework.

Also, this will only affect .Net calls or most PowerShell module commands. If you're using an external application or potentially some third party modules, you may need alternative configurations.

---

Note that as of .Net Core v2.0+ (so Powershell Core 6+, Powershell 7+) and I think as of .Net Framework 4.7+ (so latter versions of Windows Powershell after .Net Framework 4.7+ updates have been installed, and possibly only on later versions of Windows) the default value for `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` has changed from `Ssl3, Tls` to a *much* more failsafe `SystemDefault` (which did not exist at all, previously). When it's set to SystemDefault, the Powershell session will allow the operating system to determine the security protocols used, so the ciphers and protocols used will be whatever the OS is configured for. This setting is the best setting for most situations, since it should include all future OS updates and system configuration changes.